# The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique I'd property. Alternatively you can use the getRowId prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React. I'm getting Error Mui:

> The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique I'd property. Alternatively you can use the getRowId prop to specify a custom id for each row.

I tried few of the things which didn't work. Almost spent 2days on this, didn't get any solution . Any help would be of great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **mui datagrid**, Each row must have a **unique identifier**. By default, the data grid looks for a property named id which you already have in the data set to get that identifier.  I don't know why it's not picking it up in your case.   however, maybe you can try  as the error suggests  the `getRowId` property  :

```
<DataGrid getRowId={(row) => row.id} />
```

if it didn't work  you can try  :

**1 -** install uuid : `npm i uuid`

**2 -** import it in the top :  `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';`

**3-** than add `getRowId` to DataGrid  :  `<DataGrid getRowId={() => uuidv4()}  />`

Comment: after this the error is gone but values in the dialog aren't populating

Comment: well it's hard to know where the problem came from , try a demo on codesandbox I'll work on it

Comment: thanks i debugged & got it resolved.